# Running my index.js file, comes up with Error: A client is required

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to use WOKcommands to create a kick command in discord.js, but whenever I run the command I get this error:

```
Error: A client is required
```

Here is my code

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } =  require('discord.js')
const Commands = require("wokcommands")
require('dotenv/config')


const client = new Client({
    partials: ["MESSAGE", "REACTION"],
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bee-bot has started')
    client.user.setActivity('The commands')
    new Commands(client, { commandsDir: "commands"})
})



client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.content === 'bee help') {
        message.reply('Welcome the to Bee-bot Help pane.\nThe prefix is "bee" and it is case sensitive.\nbee help: displays the help pane.\nbee ban: bans a user')

    }
})

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if (message.content === 'bee ban') {
    if (message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
        if (message.members.mentions.first()) {
            try {
                MessageChannel.members.mentions.first().ban();
            } catch {
                message.reply("I do not have permissions to ban" + message.members.mentions.first());
            }
        } else {
            message.reply("You do not have permissions to ban" + message.members.mentions.first());
        }
    }
  }
})
client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

I tried changing the variable name but it came up with the same error

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `wokcommands`, you actually need to pass in one object which has the client property in it, but you are passing the `client` outside of the object which raised the error as it was unable to find a `client` property in the object. You can check the docs for `wokcommands` [here](https://docs.wornoffkeys.com/useful-links/setup-and-options-object)